# Infinitive or to+ verb

Tags: american-english

I hear all the time native speaks like this and they ignore to add **to**

1. Dad didn't have to go tell him that

*While non natives will say like*

2. Dad didn't have to go telling him that 
   Or
3. Dad didn't have to go to tell him that

Which one is correct?

Comment: All three sentences are perfectly grammatical. And therefore "correct", I assume -- whatever you mean by that. But they are different sentences, with different meanings and different syntactic constructions, using different grammar rules. What makes you think there's anything wrong with them?

Comment: I was just wandering if it adds any different meaning to it or no.

Comment: If what adds any different meaning to what? It's hard for anybody to answer a question that's not clear.

Comment: They all sound like colloquial, informal English to me. Standard English would be 'Dad didn't have to tell him that'. My own informal version would be 'Dad didn't have to go and tell him that', where 'go and' implies annoyance at the person's action.